# Disable iPhone zoom on single page

Tags: php, iphone, forms, mobile, zooming

I'm looking to disable the iPhone's zoom on a single page which has a form but allow it on others. Is there a way to enable zoom globally but then disable it on a particular page?

I'm using php.

Answer (score 1):

Try this line in your php code:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no">
```

or

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;">
```

I am using the same feature, the diference between the first and the second is the iOS version installed in the iPhone. So with this, you will probably want to find the way to know which iOS version is running the user's iPhone.

Comment: To use both in the same file is not a good idea. The first line works normal in iOS 3.x and iOS 4 but when you use the same line in iOS 5 you get another behavior. With the second line you will get a normal behavior on iOS 5. Some users report this as a bug and some of them solve it with some plugins and another users prefer validate the iOS version,